# How to not display a task in DAG based on a condition

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG and have 3 tasks in it. I would like to not display the 2nd task (middle_name) in the DAG run based on a condition. for e.g. if middle_name_var == 'false', i don't want to display the middle_name task in the DAG. Is there a way to elegantly achieve this?

```
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import Variable


middle_name_var = Variable.get('middle_name')
default_args = {
    'owner': 'test',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 6, 18),
    'email': ['tes@abc.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}
dag = DAG(
    'name',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="@once")


def first_name():
    print('John')

def middle_name():
    print('Smith')


def last_name():
    print('Doe')


first_name_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='first_name',
    provide_context=False,
    python_callable=first_name,
    dag=dag
)

middle_name_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='middle_name',
    provide_context=False,
    python_callable=middle_name,
    dag=dag
)

last_name_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='last_name',
    provide_context=False,
    python_callable=last_name,
    dag=dag
)

if middle_name_var == 'true':
    first_name_task >> middle_name_task >>last_name_task
else:
    first_name_task >> last_name_task
```

MY DAG looks like this with middle_name task...But i would like to not have middle_name task based on middle_name_var, which is set to false in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to that last set of *chaining* statements

```
# by the way i believe the comparison expression should be
# middle_name_var == True (boolean rather than string), but lets ignore it for now
if middle_name_var == 'true':
    first_name_task >> middle_name_task >>last_name_task
else:
    first_name_task >> last_name_task
```

Let me ask you: what would happen if you remove these *chaining* statements? Would the tasks disappear from DAG?

Not quite.

---

Chaining merely establishes a dependency relationship between tasks. Even without chaining, your task would remain part of your DAG (like in the screenshot that you've posted).

Here's the secret bit: a task becomes part of your dag as soon as you declare it

```
middle_name_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='middle_name',
    provide_context=False,
    python_callable=middle_name,
    dag=dag
)
```

And whether or not you set that task upstream or downstream of some other tasks, it will continue to 'appear' in your DAG. Quoting the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#dag-assignment) in this regard

> Operators do not have to be assigned to DAGs immediately (previously
>   dag was a required argument). However, once an operator is assigned to
>   a DAG, it can not be transferred or unassigned. DAG assignment can be
>   done explicitly when the operator is created, through deferred
>   assignment, or even inferred from other operators.

---

- **Q** So what should you do to 'not display' the task?

  **A** Simply not declare (instantiate) it.
- **Q** And how would you go about doing that?

  **A** Just move task declaration inside your if-else clause

> ```
> if middle_name_var == 'true':
>     middle_name_task = PythonOperator(
>         task_id='middle_name',
>         provide_context=False,
>         python_callable=middle_name,
>         dag=dag
>     )
>     first_name_task >> middle_name_task >>last_name_task
> else:
>     first_name_task >> last_name_task
> ```